# How to add placeholder <input type="datetime-local"> field?

Tags: javascript, css, html, forms

I've been trying to add placeholder in input type='datetime-local' field but it doesn't work at all. Use css for solving the issue but still unable to do it :(

```css
   input[type="datetime-local"]:before{
    content: 'Selecteer Datum';
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    width:100%;
}
input[type="datetime-local"]:active:before, input[type="datetime-local"]:hover:before, input[type="datetime-local"]:visited:before,  input[type="datetime-local"]:focus:before{
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="datetime">
        <input type="datetime-local"  >
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: check similar question asked on SO. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20321202/not-showing-place-holder-for-input-type-date-field-ios-phonegap-app

Answer (score 7):

This is kind of a wonky idea, change the input type to `text`, then  it will convert to `datetime-local` on focus using the below javascript.

```
<input type="text" id="txtbox" placeholder="Heya">

<script>
  var dtt = document.getElementById('txtbox')
  dtt.onfocus = function (event) {
      this.type = 'datetime-local';
      this.focus();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: `placeholder` does not work with `type='datetime-local'`

Comment: Then position a text (which acts as placeholder) over the textbox using absolute positioning, when clicking the textbox hide the text. I don't know it's worth the hassle. Why don't you use jquery for datetime and validation?

Answer (score 0):

Sharath Daniel is on the right lines.  A jQuery version:
http://jsfiddle.net/2e97L3d0/1/

HTML

```
<form action="" method="post">
<div class="datetime">
    <input type="text" id="datetime1" placeholder="Enter the starting date"  >
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#datetime1").focus( function() {
    $(this).attr({type: 'datetime-local'});
  });
```

});

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this solution
Here I tried to get YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm pattern placeholder y, u can make your own format
Just change value format, data-date-format and add pattern in js too.
HTML :

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.min.js"></script>
<input type="datetime-local" data-date="" data-date-format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm" value="2000-01-01T00:00:00">
```

JS :

```
$("input").on("change", function() {
    this.setAttribute(
        "data-date",
        moment(this.value, "YYYY-MM-DD'T'HH:mm:ss")
        .format( this.getAttribute("data-date-format") )
    )
}).trigger("change")
```

CSS:

```
input {
    position: relative;
    width: 150px; height: 20px;
    color: white;
}

input:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px; left: 3px;
    content: attr(data-date);
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
}

input::-webkit-datetime-edit, input::-webkit-inner-spin-button, input::-webkit-clear-button {
    display: none;
}

input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    right: 0;
    color: black;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case the previous answers do not work or you don't want to use jquery or other libraries you can set the date input to a default value. This helps on browsers that displays the date input by default as dashes '--' so the user can understand what it's for. This works quite the same as a placeholder for me.

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <div>
        <input type="datetime-local" id= "dateInput"  >
    </div>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
const dateInput = document.getElementById("dateInput");
//date string must be in format 'yyyy-mm-ddT00:00'
let todayString = '2022-03-15T12:20';
    dateInput.value= todayString;
```

*If you want to go the extra mile, set the datetime-local to the current day of year using js*

In the example below I set the datetime-local to the users current date, but you can set it to any value you choose.

```
function addZeros(time) {
    if (time < 10) {
        time = "0" + time;
    }
    return time;
}
const today = new Date();
let dd = today.getDate() ;
    let mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0 so need to add 1 to make it 1!
    let yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    let hr = addZeros(today.getHours());
    let min = addZeros(today.getMinutes());
    dd = addZeros(dd);
    mm = addZeros(mm)
let todayString = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd+'T'+ hr+':'+min;
dateInput.value= todayString;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type='datetime-local']").attr('placeholder','date time');
});
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ovrurb2h/1/)

Comment: @muztheaxe : Thanks, i got it, it's not working in chrome. Soon i  will update my answer. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

A bit tricky, but it works:

**Html:**

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="datetime">
        <input id="pholderInput" class="placeholder"  type="datetime-local">
    </div>
</form>
```

**Css:**

```
.placeholder
{
  color: gray;
}

.focused
{
  color: black;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
var inp = document.getElementById("pholderInput");

var placeholderText = "default text";

inp.value = placeholderText;

inp.onfocus = function(e) {
    if (inp.value == placeholderText)
    {
        inp.value = "";
        inp.className = "focused";
    }
};

inp.onblur = function(e) {
    if (inp.value === "")
    {
        inp.value = placeholderText;
        inp.className = "placeholder";
    }
};
```

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/sizepocabu/2/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: Tried it - it doesn't show any placeholder for me, using Chrome