# How to change placeholder of datepicker class

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

how do you change the default placeholder of the datepicker class in bootstrap?

This is my current code and has the place holder of yyyy-mm-dd but I want to change it to something different like "Enter date"

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.test, "{0:yy-MM-dd}", new { @class = "datepicker form-control" })
```

I tried

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.test, "{0:yy-MM-dd}", new { @class = "datepicker form-control", placeholder = "Enter text" })
```

but that does not do the trick.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add placeholder <input type="datetime-local"> field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30048323/how-to-add-placeholder-input-type-datetime-local-field)

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30048323/how-to-add-placeholder-input-type-datetime-local-field because the user is asking "How to add placeholder to datetime-local field" `@Html.TextBoxFor(m=> [DateTimeField])` generates a textbox with datetime-local.

Comment: Which date picker component/plugin are you using?