# Show placeholder text for input type date

Tags: html, date, placeholder

Placeholder does not work for input type `date` and `datetime-local` directly.

```
<input type="date" placeholder="Date" />
<input type="datetime-local" placeholder="Date" />
```

Instead the field shows *mm/dd/yyy* on desktop and nothing on mobile.

How can I show the *Date* placeholder text?

Comment: You can achieve that with a css only aproach. Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34385597/5701302 :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not showing placeholder for input type="date" field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20321202/not-showing-placeholder-for-input-type-date-field)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

use `onfocus="(this.type='date')"`, example:

```
<input required="" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Date" onfocus="(this.type='date')"/>
```

Comment: This is really glitchy in safari mobile

Comment: What I did as a workaround for Safari was add onmouseover="(this.type='date')"

Comment: Doesn't work on Chromium android either.

Comment: Yes but then you'll get a Content-Security-Policy error for using inline scripts.

Comment: Please note that if it is not working, don't forget to update type=“text” to your code.”

Answer (score 11):

use onfocus and onblur... Here it's an example:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Birth Date" onfocus="(this.type='date')" onblur="if(this.value==''){this.type='text'}">
```

Comment: almost works, except initial load it still has format. But this is close.

Answer (score 7):

Here, I have tried `data` attribute in `input` element. and applied required placeholder using CSS

```
<input type="date" name="dob" data-placeholder="Date of birth" required aria-required="true" />
```

```css
    input[type="date"]::before { 
     content: attr(data-placeholder);
     width: 100%;
    }
    
    /* hide our custom/fake placeholder text when in focus to show the default
     * 'mm/dd/yyyy' value and when valid to show the users' date of birth value.
     */
    input[type="date"]:focus::before,
    input[type="date"]:valid::before { display: none }
```

```html
<input type="date" name="dob" data-placeholder="Date of birth" required aria-required="true" />
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I can see that its working on Chrome, but not in FF. May be it needs the browser prefixs

Comment: Inability to style pseudo-elements I would consider to be a bug in Firefox.

Comment: This still doesn't work in desktop Firefox 109.0.1.

Comment: Firefox is correct: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#before-after-content
Pseudo-elements on input[type=text] do not work.

Answer (score 6):

```
<input type="text" placeholder="*To Date" onfocus="(this.type='date')" onblur="(this.type='text')" >
```

This code works for me. Simply you can use this

Comment: You repeated the same browser hack Leandro provided two and a half years earlier.

Answer (score 1):

For angular 2,You can use this directive

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, HostListener} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDateClick]'
})
export class DateClickDirective {
  @HostListener('focus') onMouseFocus() {
    this.el.nativeElement.type = 'date';
    setTimeout(()=>{this.el.nativeElement.click()},2);
  }

  @HostListener('blur') onMouseBlur() {
    if(this.el.nativeElement.value == ""){
      this.el.nativeElement.type = 'text';
    }
  }


  constructor(private el:ElementRef) { }

}
```

and use it like below.

```
 <input appDateClick name="targetDate" placeholder="buton name" type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

For React, you can do this.

```
const onDateFocus = (e) => (e.target.type = "datetime-local");
const onDateBlur = (e) => (e.target.type = "text");
.
.
.
  <input
    onFocus={onDateFocus}
    onBlur={onDateBlur}
    type="text"
    placeholder="Event Date"
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i did it:

```js
   var dateInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="date"]');

        dateInputs.forEach(function(input) {
            input.addEventListener('change', function() {
                input.classList.add('no-placeholder')
            });
        });
```

```css
input[type="date"] {
    position: relative;
}

input[type="date"]:not(.has-value):before {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 30%;
    color: gray;
    background: var(--primary-light);
    content: attr(placeholder);
}

.no-placeholder:before{
    content:''!important;
}
```

```html
  <input type="date" name="my-date" id="my-date" placeholder="My Date">
```

Answer (score -1):

Modern browsers use a Shadow DOM to facilitate input of dates and datetimes. As a result, placeholder text is not shown unless the browser chooses to fallback to a `text` input for whatever reason. You can accommodate both scenarios with the following logic:

```css
::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  @apply hidden; /* hide native picker icon */
}

input[type^='date']:not(:placeholder-shown) {
  @apply before:content-[attr(placeholder)];
  @apply sm:after:content-[attr(placeholder)] sm:before:hidden;
}

input[type^='date']::after,
input[type^='date']::before {
  @apply text-gray-500;
}
```

I've used Tailwind CSS syntax because it's easy to grok. Let's break it down piece by piece:

```css
::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  @apply hidden; /* hide native picker icon */
}
```

Hide native picker icon (generally a calendar) using its Shadow DOM pseudo-element selector.

```css
input[type^='date']:not(:placeholder-shown) {
  @apply before:content-[attr(placeholder)];
  @apply sm:after:content-[attr(placeholder)] sm:before:hidden;
}
```

Select all `date` and `datetime-local` inputs where placeholder is not shown and:

- Show the input `placeholder` text using the `::before` pseudo-element by default
- On small screens and above switch to using the `::after` pseudo-element instead

```css
input[type^='date']::after,
input[type^='date']::before {
  @apply text-gray-500;
}
```

Style the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements.

Comment: Not a tailwind question.