# How to attach a placeholder for input (type=date) when on mobile devices?

Tags: html, datepicker

so I have this piece of HTML

```
<input id="dob" type="date" tabindex="7" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" name="dob">
```

On a mobile device, the placeholder is not showing.  It just shows a a dropdown list and tapping on the input gives me the HTML5 date picker.

**I want to simulate the placeholder parameter on mobile devices.**

Any ideas how this can be done? thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [placeholder for input type date html5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30961704/placeholder-for-input-type-date-html5)

Comment: @SrujanReddy not sure how it can be a duplicate since the other user type=text. I'm using type=date which gives a completely different behavior on mobile devices. but thanks for the link!

Comment: ya, Thanks for pointing this out. I have suggested an edit on that question, That question is actually on date type. placeholder wont work on date types as of now. Better go with available datepicker's.