# Change text displayed in date input

Tags: javascript, css, html

Is there any way to change the default text that is displayed in a `<input type="date">` field?

Instead of mm/dd/yyyy, let's say I want to display month/day/year.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that. The question this person is asking is how to change the default text field, that question was asking how to change the format of the date.

Comment: Fair enough. See: [How do I simulate placeholder functionality on input date field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18146350/how-do-i-simulate-placeholder-functionality-on-input-date-field) and [placeholder for input type date html5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30961704/placeholder-for-input-type-date-html5). In my opinion, changing the placeholder text for an input whose format can't be changed is likely to introduce confusion.

Comment: What I was asking was not to change the format of the date.. Just the text displayed there (the placeholder). Instead of saying mm/dd/yyyy I wanted to display month/day/year.