# Date input format in different browsers

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, date, input

There is an date input of this form inside a React component:

```
<input
  className="my-class"
  type="date"
  name="dateFrom"
  data-testid="dateFrom"
  value={dataFields.dateFrom}
  onChange={(e) =>
    setDataFields({ ...dataFields, dateFrom: e.target.value })
  }
  disabled={disabledFields.dateFrom}
/>
```

Opening it with Chrome, there is a placehoder `dd/mm/yyyy`, opening it in Firefox, the month and day are swapped: `mm/dd/yyyy`.

I want to use the first format (dd/mm/yyyy) for all browsers.

So I added a placeholder but it seems to ignore it, is there a  way to show that format all the time?

```
<input
  className="my-class"
  placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" // added this line
  type="date"
  name="dateFrom"
  data-testid="dateFrom"
  value={dataFields.dateFrom}
  onChange={(e) =>
    setDataFields({ ...dataFields, dateFrom: e.target.value })
  }
  disabled={disabledFields.dateFrom}
/>
```

Comment: Is there answer for your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30961704/placeholder-for-input-type-date-html5/30961705

Comment: Is there a reason to use the native datepicker?

Comment: @danhuong no, it doesn't

Comment: @YovchoKalev I don't understand. is it a different way to make it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to change input type="date" format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format)