# Remove the dd/mm/yyyy placeholder from a HTML input

Tags: html, css

I have a register form which shows the label "Birthdate" overwritten in the same place as the dd/mm/yyyy placeholder. Is there anyway I can remove it?

I tried this in CSS but it didn't work:

```css
input[type=date]:required:invalid::-webkit-datetime-edit {
    color: transparent;
}
input[type=date]:focus::-webkit-datetime-edit {
    color: black !important;
}
```

```html
<input type="date" required>
<label>Birthdate</label>
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the "overwritten" part. See: https://codepen.io/kikosoft/pen/RwJgvLW

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show placeholder text for input type date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30961704/show-placeholder-text-for-input-type-date)

Comment: I put your HTML and CSS into a Stackverflow snippet and it displayed properly without any overlapping issues.

Answer (score 0):

you can remove `::-webkit-datetime-edit` by adding `display: none`

```css
input[type=date]::-webkit-datetime-edit {
    display: none;
}

input[type=date] {
width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<input type="date" required>
<label>Birthdate</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found what can be useful to you, also there is no way to totally delete the placeholder from a date input, because that is the format that must be follow, anyway with this you can partially hide the place holder but when it gets focused it will show again

```
   input[type="date"]::before {
        color: #999999;
        content: attr(placeholder);
    }
    
    input[type="date"] {
        color: #ffffff;
    }
    
    input[type="date"]:focus,
    input[type="date"]:valid {
        color: #666666;
    }
    
    input[type="date"]:focus::before,
    input[type="date"]:valid::before {
        content: "" !important;
    }
```

But if I miss understood what you wanted and you wanted to set your label as placeholder you can do this

```
<input required="" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Birthdate" onfocus="(this.type='date')"/>
```

What this does is that it turns your input to a date input once you give it focus, hope you find it help ful