# Changing type of input from text to date and backwards doesn't work in mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, css, input, mobile-safari

I faced with problem, when I have to set placeholder text to  input[type="date"].

I've tried this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20321202/not-showing-place-holder-for-input-type-date-field-ios-phonegap-app), but in mobile Safari this doen't work.

Here if fast [JsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JohnnyJuarez/zGKpd/3/)

Here if this part of code:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="some date" onfocus="(this.type='date')" onblur="(this.type='text')" />
</form>
```

Does anybody has thoughts about how to manage this situation?

Comment: I've tried this method: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JohnnyJuarez/ragrg8u9/)
It seems to work in mobile Safari... but my back's fillings are telling me, that should be another way...

Answer (score 0):

I have a stupid advice.I use a div to replace the input whose type is text.The true input of date is display:none;
The ios doesnot support this situation,and I try many ways to solve this ,but it's dose not  matter. Try the following ways althrough you would not like it.^-^

```js
$(function(){
        document.getElementById('div').addEventListener('click',function(e){
            if(document.getElementById('input').style.display == 'none'){
                document.getElementById('input').style.display = ''
            }
        },false)
        document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('blur',function(e){
            debugger;
            document.getElementById('input').style.display = 'none'
            document.getElementById('div').innerHTML = document.getElementById('input').value;
        })

})
```

```html
 <div id="div" style="height:47px;border:1px solid #000">
       <input id="input" type="date"  placeholder="some date"    style="display:none;"/>
 </div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
        document.getElementById('div').addEventListener('click',function(e){
            if(document.getElementById('input').style.display == 'none'){
                document.getElementById('input').style.display = ''
            }
        },false)
        document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('blur',function(e){
            debugger;
            document.getElementById('input').style.display = 'none'
            document.getElementById('div').innerHTML = document.getElementById('input').value;
        })
})

</script>
```