# placeholder being shown when clicking on another field ionic

Tags: jquery, ionic-framework, ionic-view

Hello guys I have a input field with type date. Now the problem that I'm facing is that on my computer it shows the default placeholder `mm/dd/yyyy` on my desktop but on the mobile view it doesn't shows the date picker. Please tell me why can't I see it.

```
<ion-modal-view >
  <ion-header-bar>
    <h1 class="title" style="text-align:center;">Add Action</h1>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button class="button ion-android-close" ng-click="closeActionModal()"></button>
    </div>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content>
    <form ng-submit="saveData()">
      <div class="list">
          <label class="item item-input">
            <span class="input-label">Action</span>
            <input type="text" ng-model="action.name" placeholder="Add Action">
          </label>

      <label class="item item-input">
        <span class="input-label">Target Date</span>
            <input type="date"  ng-model="action.date"  >
      </label>

      <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label">Type</span>
        <select ng-model="action.type" class="ion-input-select">
          <option value= "" selected>Select</option>
          <option value="key">Key Action</option>
          <option value="important">Important Action</option>
          <option value="additional">Additional Action</option>
        </select>
      </label>
    <label class="item">
      <button class="button button-block button-positive" type="submit">Add Action</button>
    </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: there is a simple workaround for it, hope it helps .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20321202/not-showing-placeholder-for-input-type-date-field-ios-phonegap-app

Comment: @dreamweiver I have tried it but it doesn't works

Comment: which mobile browser your verified it ?

Comment: @dreamweiver I am testing it on mobile chrome browser