# Change the input type on focus in angular

Tags: angular

```
<input type = "text" (focus)="this.type='date'">
```

Changing the input type when the user focuses on input field, default type is text.

For example this works in plain javascript, the type remains as text until the user moves the cursor inside the input field

```
<input type = "text" onFocus="this.type='date'">
```

Comment: can you explain more about this?

Comment: but why you want to change type on focus only? doesn't make any sense i guess

Comment: because I want to show the placeholder birth date and it doesn't show if the type is date, so initially i want the field to be text to it shows the placeholder https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20321202/not-showing-placeholder-for-input-type-date-field

Comment: @yerakaso check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong syntax of `focus` event, try to use it in an Angular way, like below mentioned -

```
<input placeholder="Select Date" type = "text" #inp (focus)="inp.type='date'">
```

## [Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-djjvjt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)