# Set attributes of SplitDateTimeField

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a form which I build dynamically based on data provided by the user using crispy-forms.
For certain types of data, I want to provide a SplitDateTimeField to the user. I wanted to add attributes to this field, like a placeholder, a label or a help_text, but couldn't find any hint on how to do it.

Maybe I'm searching in the wrong place, but I couldn't find even a little piece of advice anywhere even though I've been searching for quite a while.

I used an AdminSplitDateTime widget in order to at least get labels :

```
datetime = forms.SplitDateTimeField(widget=AdminSplitDateTime())
```

While it gets closer to what I want, that's not exactly it. I've searched [in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/4.0/ref/forms/fields/#splitdatetimefield) and tried with a SplitDateTimeWidget but didn't manage to make any of its attributes to work.

I'm currently lost as to what I should do so I'm asking here.

My form, simplified (I kept the crispy FormHelper in it in case it impacts the behaviour of the form) :

```
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

class ScriptInputForm2(forms.Form):
    datetime = forms.SplitDateTimeField(widget=AdminSplitDateTime())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        self.helper = FormHelper()

        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit'))
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('cancel', 'Back To Selection Page', css_class='ms-2 btn btn-danger'))

        self.helper.attrs = {
            'novalidate': ''
        }

        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-2'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-10'
        
        self.helper.form_action = reverse_lazy('index')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a DateTimeField with a DateTimeInput widget of type *datetime-local* :

```
class ScriptInputForm2(forms.Form):
    datetime = forms.DateTimeField(
        widget=forms.DateTimeInput(
            attrs={
                'step': 1, 
                'placeholder': 'My datetime field',
                'onfocus': "(this.type='datetime-local')",
                'onblur': "(this.type='text')",
            }
        )
    ),
```

The `step` attribute is useful in order to get the seconds to be displayed, whereas the `onfocus` and `onblur` ones allow the  [display of the placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23683687/19041876) while the field is empty and not on focus.