# Remove the default placeholder dd/mm/yyyy in Next Ui/tailwind input element of type=date

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, nextui

Using Next js and Next Ui input element with `type="date"` the way I'm using, it will result a text/placeholder of dd/mm/yyyy over the label! as shown below:

[image]

My component code is simple and straightforward like this:

```
    <Input                
        isRequired
        type="date"
        label="Date of Birth"  
        className=""
        variant="bordered"  
        size="md"  
        radius="sm"   
        description=""      
        placeholder=""
    />
```

I've tried to remove it by adding `placeholder=""` or trying some classes in `ClassName` but it never worked.

any idea how to remove/hide dd/mm/yyyy placeholder?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a way to fix this component the way you want it to be. But this is another idea: Start with a text input field, then change the type to a date input when the input is in focus.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/20343152/16477430

Comment: it's not working for me that way either, although I found an old school solution by updating css input [type="date"] in the globals.css and it's working like a charm but still I'm curious if there is another way to do it inline by next ui / tailwind css

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround. If you give the label a negative margin-top, it should fit fine:

```
<Input                
  type="date"
  label="Date of Birth"  
  classNames={{
    label: "-mt-6"
  }}
  variant="bordered"  
/>
```

This is not the best solution, but I hope this helps you as helped me =)