not able to remove default placeholder in React semantic UI Input type Date
I am using the below input using semantic ui react form.
<Form.Input name='StartDate' type='date' placeholder=''
                                        label='Start Date' readOnly={true} 
                                        onChange={handleChange('StartDate')}
                                        value={startDate?moment(startDate).utc().format("YYYY-MM-DD"):''}/>
                        

the above code always giving me the below placeholder even if I explicitly setting placeholder empty.
click to view
is there any way to remove the placrholder from that input?

you can check this answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20321202/not-showing-placeholder-for-input-type-date-field

It worked! Thank you so much.
